# Sinatra::Warden undefined method `authenticated?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra, rack, warden

I'm trying to use authentication for my Sinatra web application with Sinatra_warden module, but when I point to an authorized site, it says:

**NoMethodError at /admin undefined method `authenticated?' for nil:NilClass**

Here is my app.rb file:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra_warden'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Warden
enable :sessions

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  get '/admin' do
    authorize!('/login')
    erb :admin
  end

  get '/dashboard' do
    authorize!
    erb :dashboard
  end
end
```

and here is my model.rb file, just in case:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-sqlite-adapter'
require 'bcrypt'

DataMapper.setup(:default, "sqlite:test.db")

class User
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :username, String, :length => 3..50
  property :password, BCryptHash

end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nil error is coming from the "sinatra_warden" gem, if you look into it's trying to call "request.env['warden']", which is nil because:

You have to give Sinatra the Warden Manager Rack middleware via "use"

```
require 'warden'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Warden
  enable :sessions

  use Warden::Manager do |manager|

  ....
```

After you do that, you have to come up with a Warden strategy/configure the manager.

Here's an example: 
https://github.com/sklise/sinatra-warden-example#apprb-cont

Seems like sinatra-warden saves some boilerplate (gives you HAML login routes), but leaves it up to you to configure Warden.